# is there a version of kdiff3 without kde dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, xfce

I use xfce4 desktop environment, and when installing kdiff3 it pulls 173 packages(116 MB of archives) with
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kdiff3
and 251 packages (131 MB of archives) with
sudo apt-get install  kdiff3
a lot of the packages appear to be from kde desktop;
is there a version of kdiff3 without kde dependencies?
kdiff3 is a great diff tool but it would be nice if it didn't require 508 MB of disk space to install

Comment: [`Meld`](https://alternativeto.net/software/meld/) uses gtk I gather.

Comment: @pbhj although my question was about kdiff3, I am flexible on this, meld is a comparable similar tool and kdiff3 likely doesn't exist in a non-kde version, that's where the k is from probably; so if you write this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the K in `kdiff3` stands for KDE and so relies on many KDE dependencies. Also, I understand development has ceased some time ago on kdiff3.

There is also Kompare for visual diffs, with even more dependencies (as shown by `apt show kompare`).

There's a chance that `kdiff3-qt` might suffice for you though, it doesn't have all the features:

> This version of KDiff3 [`kdiff-qt`] is stripped-down so that it doesn't depend on the KDE libraries. The package "kdiff3" contains the full-featured
>    version of the program.

Instead you might want to try [`Meld`](https://alternativeto.net/software/meld/) (link to alternativeto.net as it shows other alternatives and pros/cons) which also does 3 way compares and has a similar style. It's open source and cross platform.

Comment: sudo apt-get install meld

Comment: sudo apt-get install diffuse - this is an even more lightweight diff tool, written in python, also showing differences inside lines, like kdiff3 and meld